# I want try compiler Chromium OS but not ensure_bootstrap: command not found

Tags: python

> /mnt/host/source/src/scripts/update_chroot: line 91: ensure_bootstrap: command not found

I have already add path to bashrc file

```
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/home/sdct/depot_tools"
```

but still have a problem why?

> INFO    : Bootstrapping depot_tools
>
> /mnt/host/source/src/scripts/update_chroot: line 91: ensure_bootstrap: command not found
>
> 15:32:07 ERROR   : 六  6月 13 15:32:07 CST 2020
>   15:32:07 ERROR   :  PGID  PPID   PID     ELAPSED     TIME %CPU COMMAND
>   15:32:07 ERROR   :     8     4     8       00:17 00:00:00  0.6 -bash
>   15:32:07 ERROR   :   298     8   298       00:06 00:00:00  7.5  _ python3
>   /mnt/host/source/chromite/bin/setup_board --board=amd64-generic
>   15:32:07 ERR